# ServiceStack: container.AutoWire(this) gives a NullReferenceException

Tags: dependency-injection, servicestack, ioc-container

If I in my AppHostBase descendant (web api project ) use `container.AutoWire(this)`, it will result in a `NullReferenceException` in the ServiceStack code, if I am using a web project, thus starting it with the `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` in the main method.

The error is reproduced in this Github project: https://github.com/tedekeroth/ServiceStackAutoWireTest

The error occurs in AppHostBase.Netcore.Cs, line 158:

[image]

If I remove the `container.AutoWire(this);` in TestAppHost.cs, the error goes away, but then the dependency injection does not work, meaning the `Logger` in `TestAppHost`property is not assigned:

[image]

Why does this happen, and what can I do about it?

**Setup**
Visual Studio 2019
Target framework: .NET 5.0 (Console Application)
Project SDK: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web
ServiceStack 5.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IOC [AutoWire API](https://docs.servicestack.net/ioc#autowire-registration) attempts to autowire all public property dependencies of an object which is definitely something you should never attempt to do with the `AppHost` which encapsulates the configuration and behavior of your ServiceStack App where indiscriminatingly overriding every public property is going to leave it in a corrupted state.

Registering your AppHost in the IOC shouldn't be necessary as it's available everywhere via the `HostContext.AppHost` singleton. It's also a bad idea trying to reference any type defined in your [Host Project](https://docs.servicestack.net/physical-project-structure), (the `AppHost` being the canonical example) since it creates a circular reference to your Host project in your App logic dependencies which shouldn't have any references back to its Host project, your Host project is supposed to reference all your projects .dll's, configure your App's and all its dependencies, not the other way around.

Should you need access to any Plugins it's recommended to use the `GetPlugin<T>()` API in your `Service` for optional plugins or `AssertPlugin<T>()` for required plugins. If you need to resolve any deps manually you can use `TryResolve<T>()` API in your `Service` class. For any of your App's custom config I'd recommend registering them in a custom `AppConfig` class for your Services to access like any other dependencies.

Otherwise if you really need access to the AppHost you can use the `HostContext.AppHost` singleton. If you absolutely need to have the AppHost in the IOC, just register it as a normal singleton, i.e. don't try to autowire it:

```
container.Register<IAppHost>(c => this);
```

However as mentioned earlier I'd strongly advise against it, have everything your App needs in a custom class (e.g. AppConfig) that is accessed like a normal dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get the first paragraph; it overwrites properties and sets them to null, and thus the error. Got it.

Comment: Regarding 2nd paragraph: You write _"Registering your AppHost in the IOC shouldn't be necessary"_, and I dont see that we do that. The AppHost is never put into the container and we do not reference it from anywhere else? (Our service in this case is in the same project, but that is just to make the test project easy and small etc)

Comment: Your issue is trying to register an AutoWired AppHost instance with ‘container.AutoWire(this)’